# python cannot call module method from staticmethod?

Tags: python

consider the following pattern:

```
'''some module body'''

def __foo():
    '''module method foo'''
    pass

class Dummy(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        __foo()

__foo() # No Error.
Dummy.bar() #NameError: Global name "_Dummy__foo" is not defined.
```

Why is this happening?

--

And if it's bad to name it with "__", what is the best practice in Python to make module methods available only for inner-module functions/methods?

Comment: Welcome to the concept of name mangling.

Comment: cf. the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references). "Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is now textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped."

Comment: Better reference to the docs (not for an obsolete version): http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Comment: The "best practice in Python to make module methods available only to inner-module functions/methods" is don't do it at all.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to make anything truly private in Python. This is by design. Instead, put a single underscore in front of anything clients of the module shouldn't touch, and don't touch anything from other modules that starts with an underscore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't start names with double underscores. Any identifier found in a class statement, starting with at least 2 underscores and ending with less than 2 underscores, gets `_Classname` prepended to it, where `Classname` is the name of the class. This is supposed to provide limited support for private-ish variables, but using it is often considered bad practice.

Comment: Technically it's for MI collision prevention (not that MI is such a great idea regardless...).